# ng-repeat is not iterating over array (Ionic4/Angular7)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

So, this is my first project with Ionic and Angular.
I believe I am doing something really simple but it won't work.

In my mips.page.ts I am declaring:

```
mips = ["bla", "blub", "blubba"];
```

In the mips.page.html I can do:

```
<span>{{ mips[0] }}</span>
```

and get the proper output "bla".
But when I try:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="mip in mips">
  {{ mip }}
</ion-item>
```

only one item is being created and it is empty.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: which version of angular are you using ? is it angular or angularJS ?

Comment: ng-repeat is used to itrate in angularJS not Angular (angular 2+)

Answer (score 5):

In Angular, you have to use [ngForOf structural directive(`*ngFor`)](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)  for iterating since `ng-repeat` is Angularjs syntax which won't work with Angular.

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let mip of mips">
  {{ mip }}
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Duh! I said it must be something simple ... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Angular 7 has `*ngFor` keyword to loop through collection of Array as well as objects.
so please change  `ng-repeat` by `*ngFor`  like this
`<ion-item *ngFor="let mip of mips">
  {{ mip }}
</ion-item>`